# Question concerning changing order of integration in the following double integral

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Can someone check if my solution to the following problem is correct.

(a) Evaluate

$$\int_{0}^{\alpha\sin\beta} \int_{y\cot\beta}^{\sqrt{{a}^{2}-{y}^{2}}} \log({x}^{2}+{y}^{2}) \,dx\,dy$$

(b) Change the order of integration in the integral in (a)

For part (a), I let $x=\alpha cos(\beta)$ and $y=\alpha sin(\beta)$, then applying the change of variable formula

$\int_{0}^{y} \int_{x}^{-x} \alpha\log({\alpha}^{2}) \,d\alpha\,d\beta$

$\int_{x}^{-x} \alpha\log({\alpha}^{2}) \,d\alpha\,d\beta=0$

So $\int_{0}^{y} \int_{x}^{-x} \alpha\log({\alpha}^{2}) \,d\alpha\,d\beta=0$

For part (b), the reverse order of integration becomes

$\int_{0}^{\alpha\cos\beta} \int_{\sqrt{{a}^{2}-{x}^{2}}}^{x\tan\beta} \alpha\log({\alpha}^{2}) \,d\beta\,d\alpha$

thank you in advance

Comment: The problem statement is confusing.  You have x and y as the variables of integration, while $\alpha\ and \ \beta$ are used to describe integration limits.  Then x and y get defined in terms of the other two.  I suggest you use $x=rcos(\theta ) \ and\ y=rsin(\theta)$ when making the switch to polar coordinates.

Comment: @herbsteinberg, what about $\alpha$ and $\beta$, do i change them to $r$ and $\theta$ respectively?  Like this

$$\int_{0}^{r\sin\theta} \int_{r\cot\theta}^{\sqrt{{r}^{2}-{(r\sin(\theta))}^{2}}} \log({x}^{2}+{y}^{2}) \,dx\,dy$$

Comment: @herb steinberg, I meant:

$$\int_{0}^{r\sin\theta} \int_{r\sin\theta\cot\theta}^{\sqrt{{r}^{2}-{(r\sin(\theta))}^{2}}} \log({x}^{2}+{y}^{2}) \,dx\,dy$$

Comment: @mr_e_man, is the way I did it incorrect?

Comment: @mr_e_man, so how would I go about both parts.  I am now stumped how to do it.  Because I thought i can treat $\alpha$ and $\beta$ as $r$ and $\theta$

Comment: @mr_e_man, for the inner integral, the upper and lower limits of integration should be the same, even if i treat $\alpha$ and $\beta$ as constants?  Is that correct?

Comment: Are you sure that the upper limit has $\alpha$ ("alpha") instead of $a$? It would make sense (and I think Piyush assumed in the answer) that the constants in the upper limits for $x$ and $y$ are the same. (It would be the radius of a circle.)

Comment: @mr_e_man, I typed out the question as it appears.  I first though the upper and lower limits of integration should be equal for the inner integral.  I had hard time with which graphs to draw for the two limits of integration in the inner integral.

Comment: The lower limit (actually the left limit, if $x$ represents horizontal position) is simply a straight line ($x$ is proportional to $y$). The upper limit for $x$ (actually the rightward limit) is part of a circle of radius $a$. The upper and lower limits for $y$ are horizontal lines.

Comment: @mr_e_man thank you for clearing that up for me.  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the region of integration is a sector of a disk $x^2+y^2\le a^2$ with angle $\beta$ at the center. So in polar coordinates the integration becomes $$\int_0^{\beta}\int_0^ar\log r^2 dr d\theta=\beta(\int_0^ar\log r^2 dr)=\beta(\frac{a^2}2(2\log a-1))$$

Change of variables is as follows $$\int_0^{a\cos \beta}\int_0^{x\tan\beta}\log(x^2+y^2)dydx+\int_{a\cos\beta}^a\int_0^{\sqrt{a^2-y^2}}\log(x^2+y^2)dydx$$

Comment: Thank you for helping me to clear up the liimits of integration  Much appreciate it.